# how to know when the user is in specific part of the website and when he leaves that part and display the data in the admin dashboard

Tags: users, wp-user-query

I want to display for the admin when a user visits a page and when he leaves that page

the page is for example test.test/my-dashboard. and it's only available for the logged in users.
the admin knows to know the time when the user is in that page and the time the user leaves that page.

thanks in advance and excuse my language.

Comment: You could write a function into the template for that page that records the user's time on the page and time exiting the page as part of the user_meta.  But would you want to keep a record of all the times they were on there or just the most recent instance?